# How to keep img:hover within the page boundaries?

Tags: css, image, hover

I have this piece of code:

```
<style>
.zoomimg img{
  margin-top:2px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  height:180px;
  width:520px;
  -moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.3s ease-in; 
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in; 
  -o-transition:-o-transform 0.3s ease-in;
}
.zoomimg img:hover{
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -moz-transform:scale(1.5); 
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
  -o-transform:scale(1.5);
}
</style>
```

now what it does is great. but... when it enlarges , it enlarges the most right column and the picture in it.
resulting, the website gets wider...

but i don't want that.

how can i code it so the hover enlarge moves to the left. respectively and it doesn't enlarge the current browser page?

Comment: Try `transform-origin:0 0;`.

Comment: <td class="zoomimg"><img src=http://static.boerse.de/cache/charts/US9843321061/5d1839acbf09e8c12c0b77e571197d64.png?1431090116176?=rand(1,999)/></td>

Comment: @tijnn No, edit it into your main question.

Comment: add html to your problem description.

Comment: j08691, that has a certain effect that the left-upper corner stays how it was. but i need the right upper corner to stay as it was... not the left upper....

Comment: THIS WAS THE SOLUTION: transform-origin:right center;    you can test it here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.zoomimg img {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  height: 180px;
  width: 520px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
}
.zoomimg img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="zoomimg">
    <img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```